# How could I pass nested JSON data to an API endpoint in C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, endpoint

I'm in the process of trying to pass a nested JSON object into an API endpoint for work. I'm able to easily pass simple JSON data into the endpoint by doing the following:

```
            var exampleVar = new TestClass();
            exampleVar.fieldTest = 1;
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";
            exampleVar.fieldTest = new System.DateTime(2016, 01, 01);
            exampleVar.fieldTest = "confidental";

            var testList = new List<TestClass>();
            testList.Add(exampleVar);

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testList, serializerSettings);

            var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonText, encoding, "application/json");

            var response = await Client.PostAsync("http://endpoint.here", httpContent);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(call, json);
```

However, when it comes to nested JSON data, they don't pass through the endpoint and I'm unfamiliar with how I should pass it. Here's what I'm trying to pass:

```
[{
  "TopJSON" : [ {
    "example" : 0,
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : 0,
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : [ {
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : null,
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : 0,
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : "confidental"
    }, {
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : 1,
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : 0,
      "example" : "confidental",
      "example" : null
    } ],
    "example" : null,
    "example" : 0,
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental",
    "example" : "confidental"
  } ],
  "example" : "confidental",
  "example":"confidental",
  "example" : 3,
  "example" : "confidental",
  "example" : "confidental",
  "example" : "confidental",
  "example" : "confidental"
}]
```

I've tried creating separate methods which utilize AutoFixture on each nested level of the JSON data, but to no avail. Here's an example:

```
        public ClassWithFieldProperties TestClass()
        {
            var testVar = Fixture.Build<ClassWithFieldProperties>()
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, null)
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, 0)
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, "confidental")
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, "confidental")
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, "confidental")
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, "confidental")
                .With(l => l.fieldProperty, "confidental")
                .OmitAutoProperties()
                .Create();

            return testVar;
        }
```

At the end, I tried using a nested list containing each level of JSON data to pass into the endpoint. It didn't work, unfortunately. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
            var nestedList = new
            {
                topJsonLevel = firstLayer(),
                json = new[] {
                    new  { test = secondLayer() },
                    new  { test = secondLayer() },
                },
                json = thirdLayer(),
                json = fourthLayer()
            };

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nestedList, serializerSettings);

            var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonText, encoding, "application/json");

            var response = await Client.PostAsync("http://endpoint.here", httpContent);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(call, json);
```

Sorry if it's a bit confusing. If you know of any other way to pass nested JSON data through the endpoint, I'm all ears.

Comment: Do you develop the endpoint to? It returns an error? Or what template JSON is expected by the Endpoint?

Comment: Do you really want to create JSON with multiple duplicated property names `"example"`?  Or is that just an artifact of how you write your question?  And if you don't actually want that might you please [edit] your question to give a more realistic [mcve] showing what you do want?

Comment: If an exception is thrown, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  Which line of code causes the error -- the `Client.PostAsync("http://endpoint.here", httpContent)` or the `Client.PostAsJsonAsync(call, json);`?  Can you share a [mcve] showing the client and server code?  You may be passing the JSON successfully but the server is rejecting it because it has the wrong schema.  See: [ask].